# How do I always see all items on the ground?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to show the items around me, but is there a way to keep this display on at all times?  I try to collect everything to sell, use, or disenchant, so it shouldn't be a distraction.

Answer (score 8):

In the Gameplay options you can adjust the "Item Label Display" to have <kbd>Alt</kbd> either toggle or always show the lewt near you.

[image]

Comment: tyvm..wasnt my question but i had to look this up :)

Comment: Does this also display the icons for gold? I see lots of screenshots with labels showing for all items.